# XML getElementsByTagName quits part way through

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<products>
<handle id = "B1-12">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Del Mar Handle in Venetian Bronze</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Del Mar</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B2-12">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Elizabeth Handle in Venetian Bronze</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Elizabeth</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B3-12">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin New Hampshire Handle in Venetian Bronze</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin New Hampshire</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B4-12">
    <single_price>230</single_price>
    <double_price>460</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Westcliff Handle in Venetian Bronze</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Westcliff</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B1-49">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Del Mar Handle in Matte Brass & Black</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Del Mar</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B2-49">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Elizabeth Handle in Matte Brass & Black</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Elizabeth</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B3-49">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin New Hampshire Handle in Matte Brass & Black</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin New Hampshire</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B4-49">
    <single_price>230</single_price>
    <double_price>460</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Westcliff Handle in Matte Brass & Black</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Westcliff</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B1-52">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Del Mar Handle in Matte Antique Nickel</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Del Mar</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B2-52">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Elizabeth Handle in Matte Antique Nickel</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Elizabeth</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B3-52">
    <single_price>265</single_price>
    <double_price>530</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin New Hampshire Handle in Matte Antique Nickel</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin New Hampshire</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "B4-52">
    <single_price>230</single_price>
    <double_price>460</double_price>
    <full_name>Baldwin Westcliff Handle in Matte Antique Nickel</full_name>
    <partial_name>Baldwin Westcliff</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "P1">
    <single_price>350</single_price>
    <double_price>600</double_price>
    <full_name>Pull Handle 1</full_name>
    <partial_name>Pull Handle 1</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "P3">
    <single_price>350</single_price>
    <double_price>600</double_price>
    <full_name>Pull Handle 2</full_name>
    <partial_name>Pull Handle 2</partial_name>
</handle>
<handle id = "P4">
    <single_price>350</single_price>
    <double_price>600</double_price>
    <full_name>Pull Handle 3</full_name>
    <partial_name>Pull Handle 3</partial_name>
</handle>
</products>
```

I'm attempting to get the handle items to use the data later on. However, it seems to be failing on the fifth item. When I do this:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

xml.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
   if(xml.readyState == 4)
   {
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      if(!xmlDoc)
      xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText, 'text/xml');

      var handle_list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("handle");

      console.log(handle_list);
   }
}
```

I receive this in the console:

```
[handle, handle, handle, handle, handle, item: function]
0: handle
1: handle
2: handle
3: handle
4: handle
length: 5
__proto__: NodeList
```

Also, the item at index 4 in the log is incomplete. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is an unescaped ampersand in your xml-file around the tag where the parser stops. Perhaps it's a cause for your problem?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I switched them all to 'and', and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding my comment as an answer since it seems to be the answer you could mark this question as answered.

> There is an unescaped ampersand in your xml-file around the tag where
>   the parser stops. Perhaps it's a cause for your problem?